# Export Azure Resource Groups with Tags to csv

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I'm kinda new to Powershell, and I'm trying to make a script that gets all the data from Azure Resource Group (including tags) and exporting the output to CSV.

As far as I know, there are a few ways to do it, AzureCLI, AzureRM(Powershell), and Az(Powershell).

Example 1:
This "script one-liner" gets the work done, but it requires to input the actual tags, instead of retrieving it automatically from Azure

```
$resourceGroupList = Get-AzResourceGroup | select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName,Location,ResourceId,ProvisioningState,@{N='Enviroment (Tag)'; E={$_.Tags.Enviroment}} ,@{N='Ownership (Tag)'; E={$_.Tags.Ownership}} 
$resourceGroupList | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image: csv output]

The other way I found is to use AzureCLI

```
$resourceGroupList = az group list --query "[].{ResourceGroupName:name,Location:location,ResourceType:type,provisioningState:properties,Tags:tags,ResourceGroupID:id}" -o json | convertfrom-json
$resourceGroupList | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image: This is the output:]

I really struggle with arrays and how to format them to be exported to CSV like in the format of Example 1.

Any help/ideas would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main thing to understand here is how to work with hashtables as that is what the Tags property contains. The other thing we need to account for is that tags are not consistent, no matter how hard we try as administrators, this will lead to inconsistent properties in our array of PSObjects if we just add properties for the tags from each individual Resource Group. So in advance of starting any sorting of the data for the CSV file, we need a unique list of tags across all groups. Resource Groups that don't have that tag, will need the property just so we have a complete set of data for the resulting CSV file. Anyway, less talking, more code.

```
# Initialise output array
$Output = @()

# Collect all the groups from the current subscription
$ResourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

# Obtain a unique list of tags for these groups collectively
# Use Sort-Object as per - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059
$UniqueTags = $ResourceGroups.Tags.GetEnumerator().Keys | Sort-Object -Unique

# Loop through the resource groups
foreach ($ResourceGroup in $ResourceGroups) {
    # Create a new ordered hashtable and add the normal properties first.
    $RGHashtable = [ordered] @{}
    $RGHashtable.Add("Name",$ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)
    $RGHashtable.Add("Location",$ResourceGroup.Location)
    $RGHashtable.Add("Id",$ResourceGroup.ResourceId)
    $RGHashtable.Add("ProvisioningState",$ResourceGroup.ProvisioningState)

    # Loop through possible tags adding the property if there is one, adding it with a hyphen as it's value if it doesn't.
    if ($ResourceGroup.Tags.Count -ne 0) {
        $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object {
            if ($ResourceGroup.Tags[$_]) {
                $RGHashtable.Add("$_ (Tag)",$ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
            }
            else {
                $RGHashtable.Add("$_ (Tag)","-")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object { $RGHashtable.Add("$_ (Tag)","-") }
    }

    # Update the output array, adding the ordered hashtable we have created for the ResourceGroup details.
    $Output += New-Object psobject -Property $RGHashtable
}

# Sent the final output to CSV
$Output | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force
```

I ran a test with just some basic data in a similar structure, because I'm not on my work machine currently.

```
$eur = "" | select ResourceGroupName,Location,Tags,ResourceId,ProvisioningState
$asia = "" | select ResourceGroupName,Location,Tags,ResourceId,ProvisioningState
$na = "" | select ResourceGroupName,Location,Tags,ResourceId,ProvisioningState
$sa = "" | select ResourceGroupName,Location,Tags,ResourceId,ProvisioningState

$eur.ResourceGroupName = "ParisDC"
$eur.Location = "westeurope"
$eur.ResourceId = 1
$eur.ProvisioningState = "Succeeded"
$tags = @{
    Computer = "FRDC01"
    IP = "10.11.10.10"
    Datacenter = "West Europe"
    CostCode = 54321
}
$eur.Tags = $tags

$asia.ResourceGroupName = "TokyoDC"
$asia.Location = "eastasia"
$asia.ResourceId = 2
$asia.ProvisioningState = "Succeeded"
$tags = @{
    Server = "TODC01"
    IP = "10.12.10.10"
    CostCode = 98765
}
$asia.Tags = $tags

$na.ResourceGroupName = "NewYorkDC"
$na.Location = "eastus"
$na.ResourceId = 3
$na.ProvisioningState = "Failed"
$tags = @{
    Computer = "USDC01"
    IP = "10.10.10.10"
    Owner = "John Smith"
    CostCode = 12345
}
$na.Tags = $tags

$sa.ResourceGroupName = "RioDC"
$sa.Location = "brazilsouth"
$sa.ResourceId = 4
$sa.ProvisioningState = "Succeeded"
$tags = @{}
$sa.Tags = $tags

$ResourceGroups += $sa,$na,$eur,$asia
```

If you want to see the sample, just copy and paste the data, and then omit the line `$ResourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup` in the code I provided.

Resulting output:

```
Name      Location    Id ProvisioningState IP (Tag)    Computer (Tag) Owner (Tag) CostCode (Tag) Datacenter (Tag) Server (Tag)
----      --------    -- ----------------- --------    -------------- ----------- -------------- ---------------- ------------
RioDC     brazilsouth  4 Succeeded         -           -              -           -              -                -
NewYorkDC eastus       3 Failed            10.10.10.10 USDC01         John Smith  12345          -                -
ParisDC   westeurope   1 Succeeded         10.11.10.10 FRDC01         -           54321          West Europe      -
TokyoDC   eastasia     2 Succeeded         10.12.10.10 -              -           98765          -                TODC01
```

Comment: Hey @Ash 

Thanks for the help! very appreciated. Now I kinda understand how to create the arrays, but when trying your script I get the following error. 

Which for what I understand is that its failing because there are Resource Groups without tags associated. 

 `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:21 char:13
+         if ($ResourceGroup.Tags[$_]) {
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: @maxi.mdq I have updated my answer to include the possibility that `$ResourceGroup.Tags` does not have any tags. It's never null, as it is an empty hashtable. I've done a lot of work on cleaning tags recently, so please try updated version and see the sample.

Comment: ** Resource Group tags should never be [null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resourcemanager.cmdlets.sdkmodels.psresourcegroup.tags?view=azurerm-ps#Microsoft_Azure_Commands_ResourceManager_Cmdlets_SdkModels_PSResourceGroup_Tags) in PowerShell.

Comment: `Select-Object -unique is inconsistently case sensitive` an alternate would be use `Sort-Object`  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059 @Ash

Comment: @AjoMathew, updated the answer and left a comment linking to the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your script a bit and added additional functionality.

- You can now pull tags for resource groups as well as resources
- Selecting multiple subscriptions and pulling all required information at same time
- Fixed issue when there were two similar tags like "testname" and "testname " (extra space at the end - don't even ask :P hehe). To make it more visible it's exporting tags with extra square brackets e.g (testname )
- Changed hashtable type (if I remember correctly as that was a few days ago it was to account for lower case and upper case tags).

```
Login-AzAccount

$Subscription = Get-AzSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select subscription' -OutputMode 'Multiple'

# Initialise output array
$Output = @()

if($Subscription){
    foreach ($item in $Subscription)
    {
        $item | Select-AzSubscription

        # Collect all the resources or resource groups (comment one of below)
        #$Resource = Get-AzResource
        $Resource = Get-AzResourceGroup

        # Obtain a unique list of tags for these groups collectively
        $UniqueTags = $Resource.Tags.GetEnumerator().Keys | Get-Unique �AsString | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "hidden-*" }

        # Loop through the resource groups
        foreach ($ResourceGroup in $Resource) {
            # Create a new ordered hashtable and add the normal properties first.
            $RGHashtable = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
            $RGHashtable.Add("Name",$ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)
            $RGHashtable.Add("Location",$ResourceGroup.Location)
            $RGHashtable.Add("Id",$ResourceGroup.ResourceId)
            $RGHashtable.Add("ResourceType",$ResourceGroup.ResourceType)

            # Loop through possible tags adding the property if there is one, adding it with a hyphen as it's value if it doesn't.
            if ($ResourceGroup.Tags.Count -ne 0) {
                $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object {
                    if ($ResourceGroup.Tags[$_]) {
                        $RGHashtable.Add("($_) tag",$ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
                    }
                    else {
                        $RGHashtable.Add("($_) tag","-")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object { $RGHashtable.Add("($_) tag","-") }
            }
            

            # Update the output array, adding the ordered hashtable we have created for the ResourceGroup details.
            $Output += New-Object psobject -Property $RGHashtable
        }

        # Sent the final output to CSV
        $Output | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\1a.csv -append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force
    }
}
$Output | Out-GridView
```

Comment: your script looks great, however, when you output the result into OGV, it throws an error:

Out-GridView : Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Syntax error in Binding.Path '[ Product] ' ... '(Tag)'.'.
At line:46 char:19
+         $Output | Out-GridView #Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\1a.csv -appe ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Out-GridView], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ManagementListInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand

Comment: Code should work now there was a problem with Out-Gridview and column names like "[test] (tag)". It was working fine for Export-Csv but not Out-Gridview. There's one more known issue, it's marking tags that don't exist on the resource as "-" which is fine but it's also marking the same way tags that exist but don't have value set same way.

Comment: thank you for the update. The ResourceType column is still empty?

Comment: Line 19 has a unicode character where it's meant to say `Get-Unique -AsString`