# Exporting the Specific Tags applied at the subscription level

Tags: azure, tags, azure-gov

We wish to Export a specific Tags applied at all our subscriptions to a CSV File. As Tags parameter for the subscription is not available in PowerShell, is there any other way to do it. Ex : A Tag called department and value in some subscriptions which needs to be exported with the values.

We have used the below code to extract all the Tags in the subscriptions but not a specific Tag.

PowerShell :

```
$Tags = @() 
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions)
{
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name 
$Tags += Get-AzTag -ResourceId /Subscriptions/$sub
}
$Tags
```

Any Help will be highly Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check if this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098358/export-azure-resource-groups-with-tags-to-csv

Comment: Not 100% sure what is really the question, I'd rephrase to make it easy to digest for your contributors.

Comment: @JagratiModi-AIS, sorry you can take the Resource Group tags using $ResourceGroups.Tags.GetEnumerator().Keys but for the Tags in the Subscription it is not working.

Comment: @MarkHorvath, it is now clearly explained. Please check.