# case sensitive New-Object psobject -Property Hashtable - Azure Tags reporting

Tags: tags, hashtable, case-sensitive, psobject, pscustomobject

I’m new to PowerShell and still finding my feet. So any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is for Azure Tags and I used the solution by Lukasz G. [Export Azure Resource Groups with Tags to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098358/export-azure-resource-groups-with-tags-to-csv)

How do I create psobjects that honours case sensitive key values (names of properties) ?

I have a hashtable and the key values are case sensitive. Example: Project , project, PROJECT . However after you create psobjects from the hashtable , you only end up with one.

I need to keep all those key values as is for reporting purposes. ( I know why have the three but that’s another story. A clean is definitely on the task list) .For now I have to report as is.

Want to know if case sensitive New-Object psobject is possible for what im trying to do.